# Are Johto Starters/Sinnoh Starters/Unova Starters shiny locked in ORAS?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I'm considering soft resetting for them all since I've completed the post game. I'd assume they wouldn't be because the gen 3 starters aren't and they're the main starters of the game, but I'd like some confirmation. Thanks c:

Answer (score 3):

Nope, they're definitely not locked. Professor Birch gave me a Shiny Chikorita in my AS yesterday after 1534 SRs! ^-^

Here's the live video confirming it:

And here's a full summary picture of my Chikorita: http://gyazo.com/38c7403978c8ccb69bc25fa8fef7269e

Answer (score 1):

If you want a shiny Johto starter, a better idea would look into using the "masuda method" to breed them. It increases your chances of getting a shiny by a significant amount and you can also control more about the babies, such as nature and IVs.

Comment: That's a better idea for sure.

Answer (score 1):

No they are not shiny locked...I got a shiny cyndaquil from Birch on my first try

Comment: On behalf of everyone who has played since gen2 and has never encountered a naturally generated shiny (lake of rage Gyarados doesn't count), I both congratulate and curse you.

Comment: @TrentHawkins I've found **two**. I'll share my shiny tentacruel with you, if ya want!

Comment: @RavenDreamer Nah, I'm good, thanks. I have managed to get a couple through chain fishing (and a couple hacked ones from gts), but even with all the breeding and training in the grass no game has seen fit to randomly assign me one yet. (although with my luck it will be something that can self-destruct)

Answer (score -1):

There are no evidence of that, as I know only some Legendaries or particular Event Pokemon are [shiny locked](http://www.serebii.net/games/shiny.shtml).
Normal Pokemon obtained in game could be shiny, so you can try softresetting. I don't see any difference with the normal 3rd gen starter.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'll try soft resetting for a little while then try the Masuda method c:

Answer (score -1):

As far as I've heard, only **Rayquaza and Deoxys** are shiny locked. But I do know and believe that the starters from Prof Birch are not shiny locked, because I watched a vid on youtube where someone soft reset **Mudkip** a few times and finally got shiny.

Comment: Groudon and Kyogre are shiny locked, too.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, they are shiny locked. If they weren't, we'd hear news about them.

1. There's no video confirmation or Trainer ID and Pokemon image confirmation.

Comment: Do you have any proof that they are locked?

Comment: Do you have any proof that they aren't locked?

Comment: You're the one that's making a statement.  If you don't want to back it up, that's your choice, but don't expect people to believe you.

Comment: Still, what proof do you have that they aren't shiny locked?

Comment: I've soft reset my Pokemon Omega Ruby, my Pokemon Alpha Sapphire, and my second Pokemon Alpha Sapphire 8,763 times and no luck. Many of you shiny hunters may be doing the same. Either I am extremely unlucky or Johto starters are shiny locked.

Comment: In total, that's 26,289 soft resets.

Comment: Your statement is directly conflicting with previous answers.  Which, granted, don't have proof, either.  So if you have proof, it would make it easier to accept your statement.

Comment: With 26,289 soft resets, I would have already had a shiny starter, when the shiny rate is 1/4192. If it isn't shiny locked, link me a video or some images of a non-Hoenn shiny starter. People have even said that Groudon, Kyogre, Rayquaza, and Deoxys are shiny locked, but they don't have proof of that, so are you going to say that those legendaries aren't shiny locked as well?

Comment: I *sincerely* doubt you have reset your games that often. It's a statement with zero proof. Either way, its up to you to prove your claims. Or not. Until you do, though, don't expect to be believed.

Comment: If you want to prove that the Johto starters aren't shiny locked, show me images or a video of a shiny Johto obtained legitimately in ORAS. Otherwise, there's zero proof that they are non-shiny-locked.

Comment: Johto shiny starters have finally been confirmed. Now can anybody confirm Groudon, Kyogre, Rayquaza, Deoxys, Unova starters, and Sinnoh starters, so we can avoid this argument of what's shiny-locked and what's not?